# Are there unit tests in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Can we able to write the automation test cases by using flutter for web application

I need answer for we can able to write the automation test cases by using flutter for web application

Comment: What does it have to do with python? What exactly are "automation test cases"? Flutter does have automated tests (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction), does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction goes over how Flutter does testing. That same link goes over some good CI tools to automate all of it.